# move to next tab only if i get json response as true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js

This is the jQuery I am using to move to another tab.

So, how can I apply this in my `vue.js` script. I need to move to next tab only if I got the response as true

```
if (e.status) {
  alert("Success")            
}
else {
  vm.response = e;
  alert("Registration Failed") 
}
```

Only if `(e.statu=true)` I need to move to another tab. Can anybody please help to modify the script so that id status is true only, I need to move to another tab?